# How to replace nested string value in MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I got collection with a structure like that:

```
"_id": ObjectId("64c9d5e028bcb318aa86685a"),
...
"ExamOrder" : [],
"ExamPerformed" : [ 
        {
            "authorDatetime" : "2023-08-01T16:15:00.000Z",
            "result" : {
                "value" : 114,
                "unit" : "mmHg"
            }
        },
        {
            "authorDatetime" : "2023-08-01T16:15:00.000Z",
            "result" : {
                "value" : 70,
                "unit" : "in"
            }
        }
    ],
    ...
```

What I want is to replace in every document, any occurence of unit 'mmHg' to 'mm[Hg]'.

I tried something like this:

```
updateMany(
  {"ExamPerformed.result.unit" : "mmHg"},
  [{
    "$set": 
   {"ExamPerformed": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$ExamPerformed",
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$this",
             {"result": { 
                 "unit":
                 {"$replaceAll": 
                 {"input": "$unit",
                  "find": "in",
                  "replacement": "inches"}}
                 } 
               }]}}}}
```

But this one changes whole 'result' object in every entry into:

```
{
            "authorDatetime" : "2023-08-01T16:15:00.000Z",
            "result" : {
                "unit" : null
            }
        },
```

Expected result:

```
"_id": ObjectId("64c9d5e028bcb318aa86685a"),
...
"ExamOrder" : [],
"ExamPerformed" : [ 
        {
            "authorDatetime" : "2023-08-01T16:15:00.000Z",
            "result" : {
                "value" : 114,
                "unit" : "mm[Hg]"
            }
        },
        {
            "authorDatetime" : "2023-08-01T16:15:00.000Z",
            "result" : {
                "value" : 70,
                "unit" : "in"
            }
        }
    ],
    ...
```

Can someone help me with proper aggregation pipeline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually very close. The correct syntax for using `$map` and `$mergeObject` would be like this:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "ExamPerformed.result.unit": {
    "$regex": "mmHg"
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "ExamPerformed": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$ExamPerformed",
          "as": "ep",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$ep",
              {
                "result": {
                  "value": "$$ep.result.value",
                  "unit": {
                    "$replaceAll": {
                      "input": "$$ep.result.unit",
                      "find": "mmHg",
                      "replacement": "mm[Hg]"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7I0NKukxgXr)

Comment: Ok, little update. So it works on mongo v5.0+ but target version of mongo is 3.4+. Sooo... what we need to change in your query ?

Comment: @Dariooos MongoDB 3.4 is way too old. Why in your previous attempt you are using `$replaceAll` already? It is only available in v4.4+

Comment: It is because on my local environment I got v5 and I found out that on production version is 3.4+. Anyway thanks for help :) I will try to figure something out.